# addLayout/setContentPane Order on ActionListener fail update

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

In the following code that doens't work. i have no idea on the problem. In my mind and in many other graphic framework when a set the contentPane the frame is refresh automatically. In my case when i do the setContentPane after the creation of the JPanel it works but when i do it at the end of the function after the creation of all component of my frame, the widget is not automatically repaint.

```
package tp4;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JFrame {


private JPanel mainPanel;

private JMenuBar menuBar;
private JMenu menu;
private JMenuItem menuItem;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame;
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    dim.height -= 30;
    frame = new Frame("My Frame");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setPreferredSize(dim);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

public Frame(String title)
{
    super(title);
    displayHome(Color.green);
    menu();
    listener();
    //displayItem();
}

private void displayHome(Color couleur)
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JLabel("MyLabel"));
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(couleur);
}

private void menu()
{
    menuBar=new JMenuBar();
    menu=new JMenu("Menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    menuItem=new JMenuItem("Item");
    menu.add(menuItem);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

}

private void displayItem()
{       
    mainPanel=new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setContentPane(mainPanel);//work at this position


    JPanel westPanel=new JPanel();
    westPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //same problem, here it works but if i do the mainPanel.add() at the end of the function
    //it doesn't works and it's a nonsense for me.
    mainPanel.add(westPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);

    westPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    JLabel labelWest=new JLabel("West");
    westPanel.add(labelWest);
    westPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    JPanel centerPanel=new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    JLabel labelCenter1=new JLabel("Center1");
    JLabel labelCenter2=new JLabel("Center2");
    JLabel labelCenter3=new JLabel("Center3");
    JLabel labelCenter4=new JLabel("Center4");

    GridLayout grille=new GridLayout(2,2);
    centerPanel.setLayout(grille);
    centerPanel.add(labelCenter1);
    centerPanel.add(labelCenter2);
    centerPanel.add(labelCenter3);
    centerPanel.add(labelCenter4);
    //this.setContentPane(mainPanel);// doesn't work at this position
}

private void listener()
{
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            displayItem();
        }
    });
}



}
```

Comment: `Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); dim.height -= 30;`  Ugh.. magic numbers for the task bar?  Use [`Frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-) instead.

Comment: Have you tried calling revalidate and repaint after calling setContentPane?

Comment: Also, consider using a CardLayout rather the resting the content pane, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Why the hell, i need to invalidate the frame after doing a setContentPane? It's a nonsense! I build my panel and i set it up in the frame. Why the frame doesn't invalidate itself the panel to redraw? And it not explain why the line position is important.

Comment: See [*How Layout Management Works*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/howLayoutWorks.html).

Comment: Hum i understand the logic behind the layout management. That i don't understand is why is the responsability of the developer to ask himself the revalidation of the panel/frame when we call a intern method of the panel/frame that's invalidate the view! If you have a good and logical reason to explain me why, i'll be happy.